# Sending custom structure over the network - SerializationException

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp

Morning, I've a TCP Server and a TCP Client.
Here's the code of the server:

```
public static class Server
{
    private static IPEndPoint endPoint;

    private static TcpListener tcpServer;
    private static List<Client> clients;
    private static Thread threadListen;

    private static ASCIIEncoding encoding;

    public static void Initialize(IPAddress allowedIPAddress, int port)
    {
        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(allowedIPAddress, port);

        tcpServer = new TcpListener(endPoint);
        clients = new List<Client>();
        threadListen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));

        encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        threadListen.Start();
    }

    public static byte[] PacketToArray(Packet packet)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, packet);
        byte[] packetArray = stream.GetBuffer();

        stream.Close();

        return packetArray;
    }

    public static Packet ArrayToPacket(byte[] array)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);

        Packet packet = new Packet();
        packet = (Packet) formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        stream.Close();

        return packet;
    }

    public static void Send(Client target, Packet packet)
    {
        byte[] packetArray = PacketToArray(packet);

        target.networkStream.Write(packetArray, 0, packetArray.Length);
        target.networkStream.Flush();
        OnSend(packet);
    }

    private static void Listen()
    {
        tcpServer.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Client client = new Client();
                client.tcpClient = tcpServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                client.networkStream = client.tcpClient.GetStream();
                client.thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleCommunication));

                clients.Add(client);
                client.thread.Start(client);
                OnJoin(client);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void HandleCommunication(object client)
    {
        Client handleClient = (Client) client;

        byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = handleClient.networkStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                clients.Remove(handleClient);
                OnLeave(handleClient);
                break;
            }

            Packet packet = ArrayToPacket(messageBuffer);
            OnReceive(packet);
        }
    }

    private static void OnStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server started on port .");
    }

    private static void OnJoin(Client client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID] connected.");

        Send(client, PacketGenerator.Generate(OpCodes.opHandshake, null));
    }

    private static void OnLeave(Client client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID] disconnected.");
    }

    private static void OnSend(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);
    }

    private static void OnReceive(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID]: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);
    }

    public struct Client
    {

        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        public NetworkStream networkStream;
        public Thread thread;

    }

}
```

And here's the code of the client:

```
[Serializable]
public struct Packet
{

    public int opcode;
    public string message;

}

public static class Client
{

    private static IPEndPoint endPoint;

    private static TcpClient tcpClient;
    private static NetworkStream networkStream;
    private static Thread threadCommunication;

    private static ASCIIEncoding encoding;

    public static void Initialize(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        networkStream = null;
        threadCommunication = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HandleCommunication));

        encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    }

    public static void Connect()
    {
        tcpClient.Connect(endPoint);
        threadCommunication.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to server.");

        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    }

    public static byte[] PacketToArray(Packet packet)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, packet);
        byte[] packetArray = stream.GetBuffer();

        stream.Close();

        return packetArray;
    }

    public static Packet ArrayToPacket(byte[] array)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);

        Packet packet = new Packet();
        packet = (Packet)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        stream.Close();

        return packet;
    }

    public static void Send(Packet packet)
    {
        byte[] packetArray = PacketToArray(packet);

        networkStream.Write(packetArray, 0, packetArray.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
        OnSend(packet);
    }

    private static void HandleCommunication()
    {
        byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = networkStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.");
                break;
            }

            Packet packet = ArrayToPacket(messageBuffer);
            OnReceive(packet);
        }
    }

    private static void OnSend(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID]: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);
    }

    private static void OnReceive(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);

        switch (packet.opcode)
        {

            case OpCodes.opHandshake:
                Send(PacketGenerator.Generate(OpCodes.opHandshake, null));
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

But when I'm sending a packet from the server to the client (handshake) the client get's an exception in the "ArrayToPacket" function at "packet = (Packet) formatter.Deserialize(stream);"
The exact message is: The assembly "ComDee, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" could'nt be found.
(ComDee is the assembly where the server runs).

Why? The packet-structure of the client is the same as the structrue of the server.

**UPDATE**

I've edited the Server and Client class and used protobuf-net.
But the "OnReceive" in the Client-Class doesn't get called.
Where is the problem?
Server-Class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public struct Packet
{

    [ProtoMember(1)] public int opcode;
    [ProtoMember(2)] public string message;

}

public static class Server
{

    private static IPEndPoint endPoint;

    private static TcpListener tcpServer;
    private static List<Client> clients;
    private static Thread threadListen;

    private static ASCIIEncoding encoding;

    public static void Initialize(IPAddress allowedIPAddress, int port)
    {
        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(allowedIPAddress, port);

        tcpServer = new TcpListener(endPoint);
        clients = new List<Client>();
        threadListen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));

        encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        threadListen.Start();
    }

    public static byte[] PacketToArray(Packet packet)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        Serializer.Serialize<Packet>(stream, packet);
        byte[] packetArray = stream.GetBuffer();

        stream.Close();

        return packetArray;
    }

    public static Packet ArrayToPacket(byte[] array)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);

        Packet packet = new Packet();
        packet = Serializer.Deserialize<Packet>(stream);

        stream.Close();

        return packet;
    }

    public static void Send(Client target, Packet packet)
    {
        byte[] packetArray = PacketToArray(packet);

        target.networkStream.Write(packetArray, 0, packetArray.Length);
        target.networkStream.Flush();
        OnSend(packet);
    }

    private static void Listen()
    {
        tcpServer.Start();
        OnStart();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Client client = new Client();
                client.tcpClient = tcpServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                client.networkStream = client.tcpClient.GetStream();
                client.thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleCommunication));

                clients.Add(client);
                client.thread.Start(client);
                OnJoin(client);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void HandleCommunication(object client)
    {
        Client handleClient = (Client) client;

        byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = handleClient.networkStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
            }
            catch
            {
                clients.Remove(handleClient);
                OnLeave(handleClient);
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                Packet packet = ArrayToPacket(messageBuffer);
                OnReceive(packet);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
    }

    private static void OnJoin(Client client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID] connected.");

        Send(client, PacketGenerator.Generate(OpCodes.opHandshake, null));
    }

    private static void OnLeave(Client client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID] disconnected.");
    }

    private static void OnSend(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);
    }

    private static void OnReceive(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID]: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);
    }

    public struct Client
    {

        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        public NetworkStream networkStream;
        public Thread thread;

    }

}
```

And here is the Client-Class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public struct Packet
{

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int opcode;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string message;

}

public static class Client
{

    private static IPEndPoint endPoint;

    private static TcpClient tcpClient;
    private static NetworkStream networkStream;
    private static Thread threadCommunication;

    private static ASCIIEncoding encoding;

    public static void Initialize(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        networkStream = null;
        threadCommunication = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HandleCommunication));

        encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    }

    public static void Connect()
    {
        tcpClient.Connect(endPoint);
        threadCommunication.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to server.");

        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    }

    public static byte[] PacketToArray(Packet packet)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        Serializer.Serialize<Packet>(stream, packet);
        byte[] packetArray = stream.GetBuffer();

        stream.Close();

        return packetArray;
    }

    public static Packet ArrayToPacket(byte[] array)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(array);

        Packet packet = new Packet();
        packet = Serializer.Deserialize<Packet>(stream);

        stream.Close();

        return packet;
    }

    public static void Send(Packet packet)
    {
        byte[] packetArray = PacketToArray(packet);

        networkStream.Write(packetArray, 0, packetArray.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
        OnSend(packet);
    }

    private static void HandleCommunication()
    {
        byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = networkStream.Read(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.");
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                Packet packet = ArrayToPacket(messageBuffer);
                OnReceive(packet);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnSend(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [ID]: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);
    }

    private static void OnReceive(Packet packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server: " + packet.opcode.ToString() + " | " + packet.message);

        switch (packet.opcode)
        {

            case OpCodes.opHandshake:
                Send(PacketGenerator.Generate(OpCodes.opHandshake, null));
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your reader needs to keep reading until it gets a zero or error before it invokes `ArrayToPacket`. Otherwise, you're trying to parse fragments of the entire message.

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new in tcp programing.
How can I check if the reading is complete?

Comment: Your send logic seems to be "I encode a message, send the message, and then close the connection". If so, the matching receive logic is "I keep receiving until the connection closes, then I parse everything I've received as a single message". But your receive code doesn't do that. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14715497/721269) to learn the larger, much more important, lesson.

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean.
Could you give me a code sample for the correct receive logic?

Comment: @namespace When you call `networkStream.Read` it returns the number of bytes read. You need to keep calling this method until the number returned is 0. That way you have all of your data. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx

Comment: I've edited it @David Schwartz.
Maybe somebody can solve my actual problem.

Comment: @namespace I could be wrong but you are simply overwriting your buffer on each loop. You pass `offset` as 0 in each iteration. It should probably be set to `bytesRead` but you reset that to 0 each loop.

Comment: Oh thanks - but I guess I got another problem - "bytesRead" is never 0. When I get my first message its 11 and so the "OnSend" will not called. How can I solve that?

Comment: @namespace - checkout the open source network library networkcomms.net. It also uses the protobuf-net serialiser and most of the problems you come across are probably already solved. Sending custom objects is demonstrated in the included AdvancedSend example, if you see the getting started section (http://www.networkcomms.net/getting-started/) you should be able to get up and running fairly quickly.

Comment: I got it running. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types are scoped by their assembly, and BinaryFormatter serializes the type metadata (the assembly-qualified name, etc). Having a copy of the same `class` in two places is not enough: they are not the same *type* unless they came from the same *assembly*.

Also note that `BinaryFormatter` is pretty verbose in what it stores on the wire. If you want something that addresses both of these issues without you needing to do all the serialization manually, then protobuf-net will help:

- it is very dense on the wire
- it is not bound to specific types; you can serialize with A and deserialize with B as long as A and B look similar

For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public struct Packet {    
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int opcode;
    [ProtoMember(2)] public string message;
}
```

and use `Serializer.Serialize` instead of `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Where does `Serializer` come from?